# Is it possible to have items outside recycler view scroll with the list?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have this screen where all the items are encapsulated inside a `RecyclerView` except the header. Now the problem is, the `RecyclerView` is set to a specific width while the header is set to `match_parent`. I want to be able to scroll the header with the rest of the items on the screen (so it looks like its part of the `RecyclerView`) WITHOUT changing the widths. Is that something that's possible?

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/activity_funky_recycler_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some random header"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="512dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/activity_funky_recycler_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some random header"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="512dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You should add following line in RecyclerView:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe it was that simple. One question, what is this `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` needed for? I don't see any properties called `layout_behavior`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info CardView1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info CardView2"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview2"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In Activity

```
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(true); // true: with header
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);            
final MyLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new MyLinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false, getScreenHeight(this)); // final CustomLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);  // recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // Disables scrolling for RecyclerView, however, CustomLinearLayoutManager used instead of MyLinearLayoutManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [**CollapsingToolbarLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html). It implements functionality you want.